# How to fade in / out background music in HTML ( no Flash )?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Is there a way to fade in / out background music using a JavaScript event in HTML codes ? I need to support both modern browsers and iPhone / iPad's MobileSafari.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most modern browsers support HTML5, and HTML5 lets you adjust the volume on an audio element (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#dom-media-volume).  You could use a JavaScript setTimeout to progressively lower the volume of a playing track until volume=0.

Comment: thanks. I will look into it! seems promising. it is quite weird that Google does not reply useful results at this moment.